# Do not activate work profile when adding a G Suite account

Tags: google-account, work-profiles

I have a Samsung Galaxy S8+. I manage different email addresses, one of them is managed from a G Suite account. When I connect this account, my phone is installing a work profile, if I cancel during the work profile installation, I can not use my account. With the work profile, everything is separate (Gmail, Google Drive, ...), this is not really easy to use. I want to have this account as a personal account and not a work account.

I tried to remove it by following [Pause or turn on your work profile](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/7029561), but on my phone, going to Settings > Accounts, I only have my personal accounts and can not see "Work profile settings"

I have another account managed with G Suite but I do not have this problem.

I also have access to G Suite if the solution is to deactivate it there.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

In Gsuite console

Need to go in Devices > setup (on the left menu) > mobile device management

And disable the functionality